# Autoreload in Jetty with Gradle and Kotlin

Tags: gradle, embedded-jetty, spark-java

Using the Spark web framework I'd like to enable autoreload with the embedded jetty whenever I've compiled files.

Trying

```
  gradle run -Djetty.reload=automatic -Djetty.scanIntervalSeconds=2
```

does not work though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work, because you pass this args to gradle jvm, not to jvm which runs Jetty.

As i see you using [Application Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) so you can pass args via **applicationDefaultJvmArgs** property:

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Djetty.reload=automatic", "-Djetty.scanIntervalSeconds=2"]
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: Thanks, this helped.

Comment: It is not reloading the jetty which is loaded through `gradle run` command. I've added the above line `applicationDefaultJvmArgs` to the build.gradle file. Any clue why its not working?